# r - lapply/loop or outer with two indices

Tags: r, loops, filter, lapply, outer-join

I have a dataset v1 where I want to get data of certain grid boxes.

Here's an extract from v1:

```
"V1" "V2" "V3" "V4" "V5" "V6" "V7" "V8" "V9" "V10" "V11" "V12" "V13" "V14" "V15" "V16" "V17" "V18"
43 1 0 69 60 9 19501201 1080 0 1 641 30 0 291 272 136 29 3650
43 1 1 69 60 9 19501201 884 0 1 705 30 3 290 293 136 29 3650
43 1 2 70 61 9 19501201 553 293 1 1090 30 6 264 468 138 31 3650
43 1 3 71 62 9 19501201 416 290 1 1240 30 9 303 503 140 33 3650
43 1 4 72 63 9 19501201 396 287 1 1160 30 12 334 444 142 35 3650
43 1 5 73 64 9 19501201 163 285 1 1440 30 15 377 687 144 37 3650
43 1 6 74 66 9 19501201 29 475 1 1490 30 18 386 674 146 41 3650
43 1 7 74 67 9 19501201 -257 222 1 1960 30 21 444 875 146 43 3650
43 1 8 74 68 9 19501202 -216 222 1 1850 30 0 438 806 146 45 3650
43 1 9 74 69 9 19501202 -393 222 1 1950 30 3 444 847 146 47 3650
43 1 10 74 70 9 19501202 -500 222 1 2130 30 6 457 901 146 49 3650
```

The list "v1" has the columns longitudes (V16) and the latitudes (V17) of the boundary conditions you see below.

For example, I need to filter between 80°W-30°E (V16) and 25°N-75°N (V17) by boxes of 5° each.

I want to keep all other columns from the filtered-out box.

These are my boundary conditions:

```
lon1_i <- seq(-80,25, by=5)

lon2_i <- seq(-75,30, by=5)

lat1_i <- seq(25,70, by=5)

lat2_i <- seq(30,75, by=5)
```

So the first grid box has all the info in -80° to -75° and 25°-30°, then the second box contains the data from -75° to -70° and 30°-35°. And so on until the last box of 25°-30°E and 70°-75°N.

I tried to use a for loop with two indices:

```
for (i in 1:22) {

  for(k in 1:10) {   
  
    test[[i]][[k]] <- v1 %>% 

      filter(between(V16, lon1_i[[i]], lon2_i[[i]]), between(V17, lat1_i[[k]], lat2_i[[k]])) %>%

      group_by(group = cumsum(V3 == 0))
 }
}
```

And with outer:

```
test <- outer(seq(lon1_i),seq(lon2_i),seq(lat1_i),seq(lat2_i), 

              function(i,j) v1 %>% 

        filter(between(V16, lon1_i[i], lon2_i[i]), 
               between(V17, lat1_i[j], lat2_i[j])) %>%
        group_by(group = cumsum(V3 == 0)))
```

Also lapply:

```
test <- lapply(seq(22,10),function(x) v1 %>% 
         
        filter(between(V16, lon1_i[x], lon2_i[x]), between(V17, lat1_i[x], lat2_i[x])) %>%

                   group_by(group = cumsum(V3 == 0)))
```

The output should be in the form of new data tables/lists so I guess 22x10 from my chosen coordinates.
Is it possible with these functions/types of loops? I would much appreciate some help on this. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. You're likely to get more answers if you provide a [mcve] that lets other people copy-paste your code to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @dash2 Added one!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a list of points in `test` and you have a list of areas describing the boundaries. I would use **spatial joining** for filtering a table of points e.g. using function `st_within` of R package `sf`